# Is there a way to access environment variables set up in conda environment from Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, conda, spyder

I'm trying to access environment variables set up in conda environment when running Spyder 4.1.3. I can see all environmental variables I set when I activate conda environment in Anaconda Prompt and run command:

```
conda env config vars list
```

I also have Python interpreter in Spyder set up as correct virtual environment and can confirm that environment is accessible (shows up as conda environment in lower right corner of Spyder screen and packages installed in environment can be loaded).

However when I try to call environment variables in a script, like so:

```
from boxsdk import JWTAuth

auth = JWTAuth(
    client_id= clientID,
    client_secret= clientSecret,
    enterprise_id= enterpriseID,
    jwt_key_id= publicKeyID,
    rsa_private_key_data= privateKey,
    rsa_private_key_passphrase= passphrase
)
```

I receive this error (with `varName` being a generic variable name):

```
NameError: name 'varName' is not defined
```

I checked to make sure variable names in script matched those in conda environment variables as well. TIA for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Can you share the code of how you are trying to access the env variables in your script please?

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when accessing environment variables in python you need to import the `os` package and use `os.getenv()` to access the variable. From what I can tell from the anaconda docs it would be the same method. When the script is ran all the environment variables are stored in a dictionary that can be accessed using the variable name as the key. This works very similar in the way of `.get()` works with regular dictionaries and you can set a default value just in this case the default value is set to `None` by the `os` package. You can check to see if your environment variables are being loaded properly when you run the script by using `print(os.environ)` which prints the entire dictionary of environment variables.

```py
import os
from boxsdk import JWTAuth

auth = JWTAuth(
    client_id= os.getenv('clientID'),
    client_secret= os.getenv('clientSecret'),
    enterprise_id= os.getenv('enterpriseID'),
    jwt_key_id= os.getenv('publicKeyID'),
    rsa_private_key_data= os.getenv('privateKey'),
    rsa_private_key_passphrase= os.getenv('passphrase')
)
```

I'm assuming all of these variables are environment variables remove the `os.getenv()` from the ones that aren't if that isn't true.